# Unable to have dynamic cell height with varying detail text length

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a `UITableView` which contains multiple sections with cell style type of `subtitle`. Each section has one or two `"normal"` sized table cells (one line for text label, one line for detail text label), and then one cell that contains a detail text label that needs to be larger than the others in the section (detail text label is of variable length/height).

Previously for my other tables, I would set the following for dynamic cell height and it worked perfectly:

```
GroupedTable.EstimatedRowHeight = 80;
GroupedTable.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
```

However, this current approach for cells with a large detail text label is just simply not working (cell height remains the same).

I was wondering if anyone has come across this issue before with the `detailtextlabel` resizing as I am running out of ideas on how to fix this.

For clarity, here is my `getCell()`:

```
UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(Identifier);
if (cell == null)
    cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, Identifier);
cell.TextLabel.Text = text; 
cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = detailText;
cell.DetailTextLabel.Lines = 0; //issues here
return cell;
```

When I force the `cell.Textlabel` to be the longer label, the cell reizes perfectly

Thanks for any help

Comment: Auto sizing relies on constraints "pushing" the cell outward to get to the right size. My first guess is that `DetailTextLabel` doesn't have the required constraints (top to container, bottom to container) or that `TextLabel`'s content hugging is a higher priority than `DetailTextLabel`'s content compression resistance. You could try to set it up with a custom cell (using 2 labels you add and constrain) to see if it works.

Comment: check this https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: It seems like your constrain is wrong. Please refer above link which Fahad Rehman has posted.